# setAdapter on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy mostrando un listView en un activity, que los añade dinamicamente cada segundo, adjunto código

```
public class Carro extends AppCompatActivity {
    String contenido = "";
    String etiqueta;

    UpdateData task = new UpdateData();
    private ListView lista;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaView);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            list.add("PRODUCTOS:");
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_carro);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            task.execute((Void) null);

        }

}
```

Y mi XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Carro">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listaView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Pero por mucho que cambie cosas siempre se queja de que el setAdapter apunta a un objeto nulo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que estas llamando al método `lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaView);` antes de tiempo, porque primero deberías llamar al método `setContentView(R.layout.activity_carro);` y luego recién a  `lista = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listaView);`

El listado esta tratando de buscar la vista `R.id.listaView` pero como no se ha adjuntando ninguna vista al `Activity` no lo encuentra, entonces tu lista es null.

Comment: Exactamente eso esta pasando.

Comment: Efectivamente es eso, lo que no sé es porque lo he declarado antes, muchas gracias porque me estaba volviendo loco